# Rename SO tag [idl] to [interface-definition-language] or similar

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-disambiguation

Many users of Interactive Data Language, aka IDL, post questions with tag [idl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idl) rather than the appropriate [idl-programming-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idl-programming-language).  Tag [idl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idl) is rather intended for discussion of Interface Description/Definition Language(s), also aka IDL.

I edit the tags on new questions that have used [idl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idl) incorrectly, as I observe them, but this is tedious as it is an ongoing issue, and it is incomplete as I have not reviewed older questions (there are many -- I've been on SO for only about 18 months).

I propose eliminating the ambiguous [idl] and creating a more distinctive tag for Interface Description Language such as [interface-description-language] (or maybe better, [idl-interface-description-language], to help people find it when typing "idl").

I *don't* think [idl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idl) should remain as a synonym for either more verbose tag.

Comment: Can you check the tag once and let me know if it is safe for a rename?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your attention to this issue!  I'm sorry, I don't know what type of check you'd like me to do. What is the criteria for "safe"?

Comment: Np. Can you check if all the questions in [idl] related to interface-definition-language and not the programming language?

Comment: There certainly are questions in there related to the programming language.  New ones every week, and an unknown number from before I joined stackoverflow.  If correcting their tags is a prerequisite to renaming, is there a way to correct them in bulk (if I were to identify them)?

Comment: Unfortunately nope. There is no way to correct them in bulk without contacting Stack Exchange staff. I've been retagging most of the tags in the disambiguation requests manually. We _can_ work together, and probably ask others for help if there is large amounts of them (say 100+)

Comment: Alright, let me survey them.  I'll try to get to it tonight (PST, in about 11 hours).

Comment: That's perfect. Feel free to post an answer detailing the steps you took.